# How to apply different background color in nested accordion using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

Here is a nested accordion. Class names of main and inner accordion are same, as it is nested. How can I give different colors to Main accordion and inner accordion using css ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-wilson-mo39w?from-embed

example [image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Your setting the background color of the title section and then again setting the colour of the nested accordion title. If it doesn't work like this I would try adding `!important` after the 2nd style so it would be something like `background-color: blue !important;`

```css
.accordion .title {
  background-color: green;
}

.accordion .title .accordion .title {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but If there are unknown number(dynamic) of sub accordions, How might it work?

Comment: The above css will work for 2 layers of `.accordion .title`, if you always want them to alternate between blue and green I would look into using `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` to apply the styles to the nested children.